# Swing + Spring + @Transactional = not starting transactions

Tags: java, spring, swing, jpa, spring-transactions

I'm studying the possibility about use Spring over a Swing application, applying the MVC concept.

Now I'm trying to create a @Transactional method, but it doesn't starts the transaction.

This is my code:

```
@Component
public class MainFormController {

    @Autowired
    private MainFormFrameView view;

    @Autowired
    private MyService service;

    public MainFormController() {
    view.button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            doSomethingInTransaction();
        }
    });
    }

    @Transactional
    public void doSomethingInTransaction() {
        if (!TransactionSynchronizationManager.isActualTransactionActive()) {
           throw new IllegalStateException("No active transaction!!!!");
        }
        service.doSomethingOverTheTransaction();
    }
}
```

This is my configuration:

```
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "br.com.jjw.pdv")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppContextConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource() throws PropertyVetoException {
        ComboPooledDataSource ret = new ComboPooledDataSource();

        ret.setDriverClass(jdbcDriver.class.getName());
        ret.setJdbcUrl("jdbc:hsqldb:file:dados.hsql");
        ret.setUser("sa");
        ret.setPassword("");

        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() throws PropertyVetoException {
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean ret = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        ret.setDataSource(dataSource());
        ret.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());

        EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter adapter = new EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter();
        adapter.setDatabase(Database.HSQL);

        ret.setJpaVendorAdapter(adapter);
        ret.setPersistenceXmlLocation("classpath:META-INF/persistence.xml");
        ret.setPersistenceUnitName("jjw-pdv-unit");
        ret.setLoadTimeWeaver(new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver());

        return ret;
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaDialect jpaDialect() {
        return new EclipseLinkJpaDialect();
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor persistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor() {
        return new PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager() throws PropertyVetoException {
        JpaTransactionManager ret = new JpaTransactionManager();
        ret.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory().getNativeEntityManagerFactory());
        ret.setJpaDialect(jpaDialect());
        return ret;
    }

}
```

When I click on the button, the doSomethingInTransaction() method raises my exception:

```
 IllegalStateException("No active transaction!!!!");
```

Why?

Comment: Please post the exception you get!

Comment: Have you added `<tx:annotation-driven/>` to your application context?

Comment: @Jack yes, the annotation config is above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring AOP is proxied based and inner calls are not advised.

You need to make the call on a spring provided proxy, something like

```
 SomeTransactionalBean bean = 
           applicationContext.getBean(SomeTransactionalBean.class);

 bean.doSomethingInTrasanction();
```

For example, put the `@Transactional` annotation on service method.

Comment: There are no alternative to make this work as a web mvc application? Is http://spring-rich-c.sourceforge.net/ compatible with Spring 4 ?

Comment: Just introduce a separate class (not anonymous inner class) for the ActionListener. e.g. TransactionalCallActionListener and use it

Comment: @BetoNeto Yes moving transactional annotation to injected services will solve your problem. I don't know if spring-rich-c is compatible with Spring 4, but I already do some work integrating Swing with Spring. Take a look of http://www.jdal.org/doc/jdal_swing.php.

Comment: @JoseLuisMartin solved, I put the Transactional on my service layer, and it works! Please post this as a solution, I'll accept it as the correct answer.